# User name incorrectly linked to revision history

Tags: bug, community-wiki, edit-history

The link on the author's username in [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13675/242)  incorrectly points to the revision history of the post instead of the author's user page. Ditto for other answers in this thread with no revision history.

Comment: I believe this was always so for posts which are CW.

Comment: @Martin Perhaps I should elaborate; for CW posts which do have revs, there is a line above the username that links to the revs, and a second line with a username that *does* link to the user's page. But when there are no revs, the revs line is missing, and the username instead links to the revs. Presumably that inconsistency is a bug, unless there is some rational design decision behind that which escapes me.

Comment: [meta.se]: [User names on community wiki posts link to revision histories if they're never edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303967) and [Clicking User's Name Leads Me to Editing History of Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253972)

Comment: And also a recent bug report on MathOverflow Meta: [Clicking question author username sends to revision history](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4607).